# Greek variables in 10.0.1

Tags: bugs, fonts, linux

**Bug introduced in 10.0.1 and fixed in 10.0.2**

---

10.0.1 under Ubuntu 12.04 x64 ....

Does everybody get greek variables emboldened?

Is anybody aware of how to revert to previous normal display?

The image below shows what I mean.
[image]

Comment: Please include an image of what you are seeing and a description of how it was created.

Comment: Interesting since it works fine in 10.0.0! :-D

Comment: I don't have this problem in 10.0.1 under Windows 7: http://i.stack.imgur.com/shImp.png  I am tagging this as OS dependent.

Comment: The same for 10.0.1 under Gentoo

Comment: They should have used a different font from 10.0.0 for greek letters. For example, the `\[CapitalSampi]` letter looks completely different. It would be nice to see if it is possible to revert to previous font.

Comment: I've reported this as a bug, and it has been acknowledged as such. No word on a timeline to a fix.

Comment: This has been fixed as of version 10.0.2.

Comment: @ilian That should really be an answer

Comment: @episanty Maybe it is a little thin for an answer, but I've submitted a proposed edit to the question to make the information more prominent.

Answer (score 5):

> This has been fixed as of version 10.0.2. –  ilian May 6 at 20:30

Just to take this off the unanswered list.

Comment: I believe an accept or 1 upvote will keep the automatic Community mod from bumping it to the top of the stack, too.  Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, one upvote keeps the bot away.